# I have one html file, I will set the html file in iphone based application by using mgwt .. How i am set?

Tags: gwt, mgwt

I have one html file, I will set the html file in iphone based application by using mgwt .. Please help me to set the html files in phone ...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Actually I don't see what you're asking for. What is your code? What's the problem with it?

Comment: I have set of html files and my goal is to get the html files and display in my application by using mgwt .  I tried already by using this code Frame f=new Frame();  f.setUrl("files.txt"); this code working fine in ipad but in iphone i didn't see proper view

Comment: You could update your question with this code at least. Then you'll have more chance to get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I was able to grasp from you question you have an HTML file and you want that file to act as an iPhone hybrid app using mGWT. If that's the case, then there is an huge abyss to cover before getting to that point. This is the list of general steps you would need to cover to get all the way there.

1. Get a grasp of [GWT Basics](http://www.gwtproject.org/gettingstarted.html)
2. [Configure a simple mGWT application](https://code.google.com/p/mgwt/wiki/GettingStarted) with [PhoneGap support](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/).
3. Understanding the way [GWT MVP](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html) works will also be very helpful but not required
4. Once you have that working its time to wrap the web app into a [iOS cordova webview with PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html)

Please note that you will require an Apple Mac to acomplish the last step. You will also reequire to be registered [as an Apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/register/index.action) if you intent to get your resulting app into a real device. Also you will require a good understanding of Java application development and a good grasp on how Web applications work (HTML, JS  and CSS at least).

You have a long way ahead of you.